# No Cedar supported app detected error in Sinatra Heroku app

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, cedar

Seems like everything worked fine when I pushed to Heroku as shown below. Then I run into an error on the latter while following Heroku's Docs: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby#install_the_heroku_commandline_client

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.....
       Installing rack (1.4.0)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sinatra (1.1.0)
       Using bundler (1.1.rc.7)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake
-----> Compiled slug size is 16.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v4
       http://cold-mountain-8923.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

With heroku.logs I get:

```
2012-01-11T06:36:43+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-01-11T06:36:43+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: no Cedar-supported app detected
2012-01-11T06:47:20+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-01-11T06:47:22+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2012-01-11T06:52:21+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
```

How is there no Cedar-support detected when the Gemfile and Procfile are both in there?
Also, nothing appears on the heroku webpage.

Comment: What is the contents of your Procfile?

Comment: web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS

Comment: Just recently changed it to: `web: bundle exec ruby sinatra.rb -p $PORT`

Comment: @BrandonTilley You think you can give a quick look at my source? It's just a really simple static sinatra app. https://github.com/TonyNg/Landing-Page

Comment: Hate to tell you, but it works fine for me. http://growing-dawn-4276.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me--double check your Procfile is up to date on Heroku. Here's the output of my push:

```
Counting objects: 46, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (46/46), 15.23 MiB | 774 KiB/s, done.
Total 46 (delta 11), reused 46 (delta 11)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Ruby/Rack app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.....
       Installing rack (1.4.0)
       Installing rack-protection (1.2.0)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sinatra (1.3.2)
       Using bundler (1.1.rc.7)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> web
       Default types for Ruby/Rack -> console, rake
-----> Compiled slug size is 16.5MB
-----> Launching... done, v4
       http://growing-dawn-4276.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:growing-dawn-4276.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon! Actually, knowing that it worked for you just provided me with a solution. I cloned my app on Github, deleted my original heroku app, and created a new one. Now I have it running!

Comment: @Tony are you saying there was no difference between your two (identical) apps except one ran properly and one didn't?

Answer (score 0):

I cloned my app on Github, deleted my original Heroku app, and created a new one. Now I have it running! My conclusion is that the original Heroku app was created before I made all the new changes, and commits just weren't getting updated or pushed properly somehow. By creating a new app, I don't lose a thing since the code is the same, and Heroku allows for abundant app creations.  I suspect this had something to do with git remote issues that I had not taken account for.